# Automatically log in users in Symfony 3.2 (SSO using FOSUserBundle, FR3DLdapBundle)

Tags: php, symfony, iis, single-sign-on

I am currently developing an intranet Symfony website. I am using FOSUserBundle as my User entity manager and FR3DLdapBundle to authenticate users with our LDAP directory. Logging in using credentials with the LDAP works fine at the moment. Now, I would like to make this log in process automatic.

Currently, what I have is :

A user opens a web browser and tries to access the website using the given address. He is then prompted for his credentials in a small Windows form. After a successful log in, he is now shown the website's homepage, which is basically FOSUserBundle's login form for the website. He has to log in one more time.

What I want is :

The user, after the first login (with the windows form), would be automatically logged in the website with the credentials from his first login, that is to say, he wouldn't have to enter twice his credentials. If I am not wrong, this is called a Single Sign On process but I don't have much knowledge about it.

Our infrastructure has the following : 
- IIS on which the website is hosted. 
- LDAP Server, our domain controller 
- Some other applications on same server as IIS 
- Clients use Windows, browsers mainly used are FF, Chrome, IE

Our IIS is configured to use windows authentication (kerberos protocol to match our applications). We have thus $_SERVER["REMOTE_USER"] showing the name of the user logged in.

Now, what I don't know is how to go about doing this in my website. After searching for a while, I wasn't able to find a complete solution (answers lacking examples, directions or not matching my setup or environment). Here are some answers I already read, but were not enough to help me : 
- [Symfony LDAP log in automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35405355/symfony-ldap-log-in-automatically) 
- [Symfony authentification with LDAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29072106/symfony-authentification-with-ldap) 
- [Kerberos authentication with Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20147843/kerberos-authentication-with-symfony2) 
- https://openclassrooms.com/forum/sujet/symfony2-fosuserbundle-connecter-un-utilisateur (in French)

My security.yml :

```
security:

erase_credentials: false

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

firewalls:
    main:
        pattern:    ^/
        fr3d_ldap: ~
        form_login:
            always_use_default_target_path: true
            default_target_path: /profile
        logout:     true
        anonymous:  true

providers:
    chain_provider:
        chain:
            providers: [fos_userbundle, fr3d_ldapbundle]
    fr3d_ldapbundle:
        id: fr3d_ldap.security.user.provider
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username

encoders:
    EDF\UserBundle\Entity\User: plaintext
```

I am now looking for help as I ran out of ideas.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think your answer matches my question. Is it possible you got the wrong thread ? Sorry if I am wrong, and can you then explain what you are trying to say ?

Comment: Yikes, I did post in the wrong question. Sorry about that!